# How to get the lat&lon (from map.getCenter()) values on each map 'move'(pan,zoomin&out)?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have created a 'dynamic java project'(java7) using eclipse luna and succesfully rendered a map from postgis-postgresql database using geoserver & openlayers-2.13.
Now I want to get the latitude & longitude values of center point on each map movement,so that I can print the map with current position. My code is :

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
var layer  = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "District Boundary","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms/sde", {layers: 'sde:district_boundary' } );
map.addLayer([layer]);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(76.452, 10.528), 7);
map.events.register("move", map, function() {
    console.debug('lat : '+map.getCenter().lat());
});
```

But I am getting error like this ***TypeError: map.getCenter(...).lat is not a function***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear: `lat` is a property, not a function, so you should not call it via `p.lat()` but `p.lat`.

Also, the error message indicates you didn't post the code you're *really* running - don't do that as it may make investigating your problem impossible.

Comment: Thank you..I have edited my question..The error was my mistake but putting '()'